# Enable neon on ARM cortex-a series

Tags: assembly, arm, neon, bare-metal, cortex-a

I want to initialize on a bare metal cortex A-15 the NEON cp. After following [ARM's directives](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0438g/CDEDBHDD.html) I wrote this sequence at the end of my platform init sequence:

```
MOV r0, #0x00F00000
MRC p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 2
ORR r0, r0, #0x0C00 
BIC r0, r0, #0xC000 
MCR p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 2
ISB
MRC p15, 4, r0, c1, c1, 2
BIC r0, r0,  #0x0C00
BIC r0, r0, #(3<<14)
MCR p15, 4, r0, c1, c1, 2
ISB
MOV r3, #0x40000000
VMSR FPEXC, r3
```

I get this error:

```
Error: operand 0 must be FPSCR -- `vmsr FPEXC,r3'
```

I am using     `arm-eabi-as --version`:

```
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.21
Copyright 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-eabi'.
```

If I change `FPEXC` to `FPSCR` the program compiles and the running raise unhandler exception:

```
MRC p15, 4, r0, c1, c1, 2
```

Comment: @artlessnoise any idea why `MRC p15, 4, r0, c1, c1, 2` raises an exception and changes the mode to `Undefined` in [CPSR register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0290g/I27695.html)? I am running the above assembly code as `Supervisor`.

Comment: @artlessnoise, that is what [ARM claims](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0438g/CDEDBHDD.html)

Comment: I think you need `MRC p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 2`; there is no `4`.  That number is important.  You read *Using the Advanced SIMD and VFP in Hyp mode*; You are not using the *virtualization extensions*?  Also, I don't think you need this if you are not using *TrustZone*.

Comment: @artlessnoise can you post an answer with the full sequence ?

Comment: `eee8Ra10` where `R` is the register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence for initializing the VFPU can be found in [*u-boot* source](https://github.com/Timesys/u-boot-timesys/blob/2011.12-mvf/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/vybrid/lowlevel_init.S).

```
.macro init_vfpu
  ldr r0, =(0xF << 20)
  mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 2
  mov r3, #0x40000000
  .long 0xeee83a10
  /* vmsr FPEXC, r3 */
.endm /* init_vfpu */
```

As documented in the [*binutils* mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-binutils/2012-03/msg00047.html), the *vmsr FPEXC bug* has been fixed in the *binutils* [2.23 branch](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=commit;f=gas/config/tc-arm.c;h=1a63e03736c60da3a2d0954dcd262c5756308799) as well as the HEAD and the 2.24 development branch which will be released shortly.  Fixes exist in the 2.23.1 and 2.23.2 releases of *binutils*.

Here is a sample session,

```
$ cat t.S
init_vpu:
  ldr r0, =(0xF << 20)
  mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 2
  mov r3, #0x40000000
  vmsr FPEXC, r3
  bx  lr
  .ltorg
$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mfpu=neon t.S -o t.o
$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as --version | grep assembler
GNU assembler (crosstool-NG hg+default-86a8d1d467c8) 2.23.1
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-none-linux-gnueabi'.
$ objdump --version | grep Binutils
GNU objdump (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.23.2
$ objdump -S t.o 

t.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <init_vpu>:
   0:   e3a0060f        mov     r0, #15728640   ; 0xf00000
   4:   ee010f50        mcr     15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {2}
   8:   e3a03101        mov     r3, #1073741824 ; 0x40000000
   c:   eee83a10        vmsr    fpexc, r3
  10:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

The above sequence should work for all of the *Cortex-A* series.  The sequence is for a system without *virtualization* or *TrustZone* active.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update binutils from git. This issue has been fixed earlier this year in [this commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=commit;f=gas/config/tc-arm.c;h=88691fc2370184c2c1578f0b14a7a0f75ca6e8d7), but apparently there has been no release since then.
Alternatively, encode the instruction manually.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE binutils isn't gcc.
Whoever downvoted, care to explain?

Comment: @artlessnoise Ok, I'll take your word for it. The commit I found is dated later than 2.23 and I don't see 2.24 release yet (not tagged).

Comment: I see. I should have gone back more, I just found the most recent change and assumed that was the first fix.

Comment: @Jester I'm not the one who downvoted your answer. I'm upvoting it right now. You deserved this with your answer :)